# Haml to Erb manual conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, erb

hi guys i have an issues on how to transform the following into Erb version templating.
Following are my code in Haml:

```
%li.public.radio{"data-aspect_id" => "public", :class => ("selected" if publisher_public)}
```

and

```
%li.divider.all_aspects.radio{:style => "padding-bottom: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;", "data-aspect_id" => "all_aspects", :class => ("selected" if (!publisher_public && all_aspects_selected?(selected_aspects)))}
```

my solutions in Erb are as follow, but seems not functioning well

```
<li class="public radio" data-aspect_id="public" class = "#{ 'selected' if publisher_public}">
</li>
```

and

```
<li class="all_aspects divider radio" style="padding-bottom: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;" data-aspect_id="all_aspects" class = "#{ 'selected' if (!publisher_public && all_aspects_selected?(selected_aspects))}"></li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably only want one `class` attribute in the HTML and `#{...}` won't do string interpolation in ERB (unless of course it is inside a Ruby chunk). You probably want something more like this:

```
<li class="public radio <%= 'selected' if publisher_public %>" data-aspect_id="public">
```

Similarly for the other `<li>`.